# Getting Related Post from Multiple Taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, post, categories, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have a custom post type called Videos and I have several taxonomies for each. I have one taxonomy for Age, one for Program type, and one for Original/Syndicated. When I click on a single video post I want display a list of four related post pulling from these three taxonomies. I've used the code below to show related post for one taxonomy but is it possible to pull from multiple taxonomies?

```
<div id="related-posts">
<h3>Related Videos</h3>
<?php
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'video_age', 'string');
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

if(!empty($terms)){
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        query_posts( array(
        'video_age' => $term->slug,
        'showposts' => 4,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) );
        if(have_posts()){
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="related-post">
                <?php the_title();?>
                <div class="ilc-excerpt">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();
        }
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query look for tax_query

Answer (score 0):

You could use [This snippet](https://gist.github.com/dannystyleart/18acb2b6535989096bb1) or extend it for your own taste :)